# Same URL (question) found in other Site

Tags: discussion

Hi i am searching something in Google and i got the question http://w3facility.org/question/send-an-image-from-android-using-ksoap2-to-a-webservice/ from this [site](http://w3facility.org/).

Now, found the same question in SO. Here is the [Send an image from Android using ksoap2 to a webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280862/send-an-image-from-android-using-ksoap2-to-a-webservice)

and when i saw the exact same question other site in that question there is Option **Source Link: Stack Exchange**. See below the snap

Now, my question is is that site is **Child of SO** then why this site is not showing up in **SO Community**. and if not then how they site grab all the data from SO. Or it's an part of **SO**.

[image]

Comment: This site is not part of Stack Exchange, it is pulling the data and displaying it. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: They're actually allowed to have content from SO, as long as a few simple requests are met (link to the original source, credit given to the author, etc...you can find a full list somewhere on MSE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [website's about page](http://w3facility.org/about-us/) actually does a pretty good job of explaining this.

Here's what they say:

> We have build this facility over the Stack Exchange sql dump as well as Yahoo Answers feed to populate these questions archive so that users may get maximum relevant answers to all their questions in one place.
>
> This presentation of data is completely legal and follows all the attribution requirements of relevant sites mentioned [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

And they are correct. It is sort of annoying to have sites basically try to copy the Stack Exchange system, **but it *is*, in fact, allowed**, as long as a couple of rules are followed.

You can read the official SE blog post about all of this [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), but the most important part is this:

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this
> content, we require that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack
>    Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a
>    discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original
>    question on the source site (e.g.,
>    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for
>    every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to
>    their user profile page on the source site (e.g.,
>    https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Comment: So is that possible that I request some of data from my android app to SO? And I'll develop app for SO.

Comment: @MD yes, you can pull SO data and display it as long as you follow the rules a guidelines laid out in the official SE blog post that I linked to in my post

Comment: Thanx Alex k Its very helpful.